# Drush cc all doesn't flush and rebuild templates?

Tags: drush

I am trying to clear the cache using **Drush cc all** because I deleted a function in the module/theme files and the site won't render...

I always have to login in as admin, performance > Clear all caches

This works...what is the equivalent Drush command?

Comment: That is the equivalent drush command. It should have the same effect

Comment: Yep that always works for me too - are you sure the deleted function isn't being explicitly called from another function? If you check your server logs it should tell you what module/include the error originates from

Comment: Weird...I have tried and tested and it's not working as expected...I login as admin and clear cache through UI works...drush cc all...doesn't seem to flush the templates :s the deleted function is a theme hook theme_textfield in this case. I removed it...refresh page and bam no fields appear...called drush cc all and it didn't work...restored function...logged in...removed function...refreshed cache and voila the default was used as expected.

Comment: Interesting. Any chance you're using a non-db cache that may not be being flushed correctly, or maybe an incorrect cache-bin prefix in settings.php?

Answer (score 2):

I did not try to reproduce your exact situation, but some operations called by cache_clear_all write / remove files from the filesystem. If your filesystem permissions are not correct, then `drush cc all` will do all of the database clearing just fine, but will leave the other operations undone.

There are two potential solutions to this:

1. `sudo -u www-data drush cc all`

Some folks don't like to use 'sudo' with 'drush', but if you run Drush as the webserver user, the cache-clear should work.

2. set the permissions of your webserver files so that the user that you run Drush as can read/write to the filesystem.

I usually make my webserver files owned by a 'www-admin' user in production, and I make them owned by the user I log in as on my development system.  I set the group of all files to www-data, and make those that the webserver needs to write to group-writable.  This works pretty well for Drush + Drupal access on Drupal 7.

Comment: I think the OP is experiencing something slightly different (might be wrong) - from the last comment on the question it sounds like the theme registry isn't being re-built, I'm not sure file permissions could affect that directly. Or could they?

Comment: Seems to have something to do with the filesystem from the symptoms, so I'd try that first. Stepping through the cache-clear op would be the next step, but fairly labor-instensive.

Comment: I was executing drush as root in this case so it can't be a file permissions issue...I was thinking (didn't occur to me earlier) that Drush has no way of knowing which site I want to flush so I assume I have to invoke Drush from with the /drupal/sites/www.something.com/ directory in order for it to know which database, etc to even flush??? It doesn't error though which I thought was weird

Comment: cd to the folder that contains settings.php to select the Drupal site to operate on, or specify via --root and --uri.  `drush cc drush` will say that the Drush cache was cleared if no Drupal site is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I was invoking drush from any location I was currently in...when I cd'ed into the sites folders accordingly it seems to work. Not sure how I missed that.